# signalr-objc Client Problems with SignalR server

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, signalr

I am using the latest build (from GitHub, not Cocoapods) of the signalr-objc client.

I am getting some (to me) non-deterministic errors while connecting.

After calling the /negotiate URL, the server responds with a connection ID and token.

After the client continues, the server will in 9 times out of 10 throw the "The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format" InvalidOperationException. However, for 1 out of 10 times (or so), it works and the client successfully connects and is able to send and receive messages.

I've tried putting some thread sleeps in the Objective C code to see if there's some sort of timing issue, but to no avail.

Does anyone know what's going on here? What could be causing this?

EDIT: I might add that I am successfully able to connect to the server using the .NET client.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. It turns out (which wasn't documented anywhere) that signalr-objc does not work with the latest (2.0) version of the SignalR server.

I downloaded the 1.1.3 version (the last stable release before 2.0) and now everything works just fine.